# Polymer 0.5 auto-binding template "template-bound" event 1.0 equivalent

Tags: polymer

in polymer 0.5 a auto-binding template fired a "template-bound" event.

```
document.querySelector('#app').addEventListener('template-bound', function () {})
```

what would be the polymer 1.0 equivalent?

Comment: it looks like the "WebComponentsReady" event will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this:

Update to 1.0 syntax: template-bound > dom-change
You can see the change in this commit of the StarterKit

https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/commit/eba941318b2816a2e9285d4214eb9a1a937781c9